# How to GetAllChildren of a SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, nodes, selecteditem

In my program I would like to get all the children of a parent node so that I can add a new node to it. In the past I used this approach:

```
//This gets all the children of a parent node depending on it's DisplayName
var node = ObservableCollection.GetAllChildren(x => x.Children).Distinct().ToList().First(x => x.DisplayName == nameOfNode);
node.Children.Add(CreateNode(newNodeName));
```

Now I would like to `GetAllChildren` based off of my `SelectedItem` property, which is fully functional. Is it possible to do that with the `GetAllChildren` method? If so, how?

**Addition 1:**

My `SelectedItem` property is of type ViewModel. The `ObservableCollection` is also of type `ViewModel`, so basically `SelectedItem` tells the program which ViewModel is selected.

**Addition 2:**

I cannot just simply add to the Parent Node. I have to check how many children there are for other reasons in this program before adding.

Comment: I might be wrong but to me you seem to be asking how to find a node which equals SelectedItem and add a new node to it. Why dont you just use SelectedItem.Add instead??? It would sort of save you the searching by reference equals.

Comment: If I do that will it have the same effect? Strike that.. I do need to check how many children there are that belong to the parent node.

Comment: That is a cute qustion to ask. I think it should have same effect but to be honest you are the one next to the code not me. Soooo try it out. If it doesnt work at least we know one more way how not to do it. Edison knew 100 ways not make a light bulb. :)

Comment: Okay, that works great for adding! But is there a way that I can check how many children the Parent Node has before adding to it?

Comment: It did work for adding? Wow, I am pretty good at guessing. Well Eric I dont know much about your actual data structure but you could use some kind of linq statement to find out the Count().

Comment: Yes, it worked for adding and it looks like I can use `SelectedItem.Children.Count()` to check the number of children

Comment: I have to make a correction and say that `SelectedItem.Children.Add()` worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but to me you seem to be asking how to find a node which equals SelectedItem and add a new node to it. Why dont you just use SelectedItem.Add instead??? It would sort of save you the searching by reference equals.

For counting the children just use the Linq Count() method :)

Comment: You might want to add that I used `SelectedItem.Children.Count()` to get the number of children, and then `SelectedItem.Children.Add()` to add nodes.